# Heroku giving error on setting a field on a model for its view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm very simply setting a field on my User model in the `UsersController#new`:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.next_billing_cycle = Date.today

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end
```

Works perfect in my development environment. My User model has `attr_accessible :next_billing_cycle` so it has a corresponding `date_select` set of fields too:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :next_billing_cycle
end
```

However, in Heroku, I get this error:

```
2012-11-28T21:02:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/new" for 173.55.174.235 at 2012-11-28 21:02:47 +0000
2012-11-28T21:02:47+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/new host=example.com fwd=173.55.174.235 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=402ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-11-28T21:02:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-28T21:02:47+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `next_billing_cycle=' for #<User:0x00000004f47618>):
2012-11-28T21:02:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-28T21:02:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 322ms
2012-11-28T21:02:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-11-28T21:02:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `new'
2012-11-28T21:02:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
```

***UPDATE***: I should've made clear, I **did** run `heroku rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Did you run all migrations on your remote db?

Comment: If you ran migrations after Heroku launched your app, you might need to `heroku restart`, since Rails caches database schemas by default in production.

Comment: @willglynn - I did not do a `heroku restart`. I can't at the moment, but will try that in the near future.

Comment: I'm just reviewing unsolved questions of mine and I came across this one... I solved it, but don't remember at all how I did it :(, sorry. I'm guessing that heroku restart fixed it as I don't remember doing anything after that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use `attr_accessor`? Or is `next_billing_cycle` a column in the DB?

Comment: If it works in the dev environment but not on Heroku, maybe you have a migration issue. Are you sure the column exists on Heroku?

Comment: He's using `attr_accessible`, not `attr_accessor`.

Comment: @willglynn right. If it was attr_accessor then next_billing_cycle= would be defined. attr_accessible is just a whitelist, as I'm sure you know.